# AS/400 STRSDA - define tab navigation order

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am creating screen in STRSDA and I want to change TAB key navigation order. By default it's start on first editable field on screen. Is there any possibility to start on for example third field?

Answer (score 0):

Add DSPATR(PC) to field on which want to start TAB cycle